# Is <!----> a valid HTML or XML comment?

Tags: c#, xml, html, gitlab

I wrote a C# routine to look at [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) repository sites using the Microsoft webclient class, and then added GitLab.

I started out with the https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/ repository collection.

GitHub works fine; but the GitLab site uses "<!---->" comment items in their HTML coding. The webclient does not parse this correctly; saving the web page has missing content.

Is this an invalid coding by GitLab or does webclient have a bug? The usual browsers (Firefox and Chrome) parse the page properly, but they may do so even though it is invalid coding maybe.

Answer (score 1):

`<!--`: Signifies the beginning of an HTML comment.

`-->`: Signifies the end of an HTML comment

These are included in the HTML markup specifications and are valid. However, they should not be included in the UI representation of the page, nor should any content between.

Technically, `<!---->` is valid.

The specifications can be found here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comments

XML comments follow similar guidelines: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments

Comment: So what is the answer to the question? - *"Is this an invalid coding by GitLab or does webclient have a bug?"*

Comment: I would say it's not an invalid coding by GitLab since it's valid HTML. However, I hesitate in saying that it's a bug in WebClient since I'm unsure if there are other issues in the HTML that may be causing an issue. Since I have limited information and haven't experienced/debugged it myself, I decided to simply state that it's unlikely to be a problem with the HTML produced by GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

Not only this is a valid comment, but [GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#html-comment-support-in-the-content-editor) (December 2022) propose to better preserve said comments:

> ### HTML comment support in the Content Editor
>
> When you collaborate on a wiki page or blog post, you often come across inline HTML comments that are not meant to be rendered.
>
> Previously, the Content Editor would ignore these comments to reflect what the actual content would look like.
> The problem, however, was that making edits in the Content Editor could unexpectedly remove these comments from the file.
>
> With this release, you can insert new HTML comments inline and edit comments already on the page.
>
> These comments appear in a way that indicates they won’t be rendered.
> This feature can help you manage longer wiki pages and is an important step towards editing issue descriptions and comments in future releases.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_7/create-wysiwyg-comments.png -- HTML comment support in the Content Editor]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/wiki/#content-editor) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/342173).